# Is git bundle create supported by SourceTree?

Tags: git, synchronization, offline, atlassian-sourcetree

The Git command [bundle](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) is used to synchronize Git repositories that are not directly connected. For example the following command creates a file from master branch:

```
git bundle create file.bundle master
```

The file can the be fetched into the repository on another machine.

Is the bundle creation supported by the Git GUI Atlassian SourceTree? I was not able to find a menu entry. The web search has not lead to any hint, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is still no menu entry or something like that.

The solution is to use the command shell (I am using the UI in German, there is is called Eingabeaufforderung). Using this shell all the git commands are available. It is even possible to use most or all commands similar to other Unix-like environments, e.g. `git ls-files -z | xargs -0 rm`.

Comment: do you mean command shell as a menu feature in sourcetree or in a separate terminal?

Comment: edit: find out: it's an icon on the toolbar on the right (standard conf)